# How to position menu in center and remove lines between text?

Tags: html, css, styles, mybb

I started to work on personal forum, and wanted to integrate menu into header. i inserted links into template, but for some reason, menu is right alligned and have some lines between links. How to center the entire menu, and remove that lines between each link? Problem can be seen [here](http://mythicalservers.net/forum/).

[image]

Comment: Include a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) **in the question itself**, not a link to your website.

Comment: Read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/4305494) @StefanBob.

Comment: Yea i know it makes sense to have the code for future reference blah blah. That's why I deleted that comment. And I guess you reread the guidelines to delete the second part of your snarky comment ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.menuwrap {
   border: none;
}

.majestic {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.majestic li a {
    border: none;
}
```

Badabing badaboom. I'm writing `border: none;` here but if you have access to the CSS just delete the `border-left` and `border-right` styles that are in there already.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks !!

Comment: Hi, i still see two lines from left and from right there.. Can you take a look ?

http://i.imgur.com/cHl8pta.png?1

Comment: Yea, i'll edit answer. But this one should be easy for you to catch lol

Comment: You should listen to Ricky and post your full html + css to the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141740/discussion-between-dora-and-stefanbob).